# How do I get direct input in UI using InputField

Tags: unity-game-engine

Does anyone know if it is possible to input text directly in the GUI in Unity (IOS)?

As it is now I get the input field to type in on top of the keyboard and I would like to type directly on the UI.

[image: InputField]

Comment: From user perspective, the current version is convenient enough, just a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

The part I don't get it is: If virtual keyboard is not you looking for. How do you input text without virtual keyboard if I'm on mobile device??
Wireless physical keyboard? Voice command? Gesture? Gyro? Touch screen?

What do you mean by "Type directly on the UI"? Type with What?

If your answer is Touch screen, you'll end up make couple of Button on Unity UI, then what's the difference between virtual keyboard? Unless you limit your number of button.

If you just think default keyboard is too much for the number, you can achieve by open virtual keyboard with [TouchScreenKeyboardType.NumberPad](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MobileKeyboard.html) type.

Comment: What I am looking for is to have the virtual keyboard visible but the actual text goes directly into the UI InputField and not in an "extra" input-box on top of the virtual keyboard. See the picture.

Comment: I see what you mean now. I've see some post of same issue [Remove Keyboard Input Field](https://forum.unity.com/threads/remove-keyboard-input-field.517381/), [Removing Android keyboard additional input field](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1408712/removing-android-keyboard-additional-input-field.html?_ga=2.205291218.371780796.1590575974-85287500.1585593965). They all point to **hideInput** setting, see **Text Preview** section of [Mobile Keyboard](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MobileKeyboard.html?_ga=2.205291218.371780796.1590575974-85287500.1585593965)

Comment: Maybe this: By default, an edit box will be created and placed on top of the keyboard after it appears. This works as preview of the text that user is typing, so the text is always visible for the user. However, you can disable text preview by setting TouchScreenKeyboard.hideInput to true. Note that this works only for certain keyboard types and input modes. For example, it will not work for phone keypads and multi-line text input. In such cases, the edit box will always appear. TouchScreenKeyboard.hideInput is a global variable and will affect all keyboards.